# Node.js using hex got wrong final block length

Tags: node.js, encryption

I was trying to encrypt/decrypt file using node.js. I wrote 4 pairs of function for encrypt and decrypt. If I didn't set any encoding, they work. When I tried some encoding, like 'hex', 'base64', they fail. All errors happened at decrypt the encrypted file.

Especially using pipe, I don't know how to set the input encoding and output encoding.

Error

```
  const ret = this._handle.final();
                           ^

Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
    at Decipheriv.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:164:28)
    at ReadStream.readStream.on.on (C:\test\tutorial\scrypt\node\index.js:111:37)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1125:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Code (index.js)

```
const crypto = require( 'crypto' )
const fs = require( 'fs' )

const algorithm = 'aes-192-cbc'
const password = 'testing'
const salt = 'salt'

const key = crypto.scryptSync( password, salt, 24 )
const iv = Buffer.alloc( 16, 0 )

function encrypt_pnull() {
    let inf = 'copyright.txt'
    let outf = 'encrypted_pnull.enc'
    cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( algorithm, key, iv )
    input = fs.createReadStream( inf )
    encrypted = fs.createWriteStream( outf )
    input.pipe( cipher ).pipe( encrypted )
}

function decrypt_pnull() {
    let inf = 'encrypted_pnull.enc'
    let outf = 'decrypted_pnull.txt'
    decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv( algorithm, key, iv )
    inp_enc = fs.createReadStream( inf )
    decrypted = fs.createWriteStream( outf )
    inp_enc.pipe( decipher ).pipe( decrypted )
}

function encrypt_phex() {
    let inf = 'copyright.txt'
    let outf = 'encrypted_phex.enc'
    cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( algorithm, key, iv )
    input = fs.createReadStream( inf )
    encrypted = fs.createWriteStream( outf )
    // cipher.setEncoding( 'hex' )
    cipher.setEncoding( 'base64' )
    input.pipe( cipher ).pipe( encrypted )
}

function decrypt_phex() {
    let inf = 'encrypted_phex.enc'
    let outf = 'decrypted_phex.txt'
    decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv( algorithm, key, iv )

    /// None of the following setting work
    // decipher.setEncoding( 'hex' )
    // decipher.setEncoding( 'utf8' )
    decipher.setEncoding( 'base64' )

    inp_enc = fs.createReadStream( inf )
    decrypted = fs.createWriteStream( outf )
    inp_enc.pipe( decipher ).pipe( decrypted )
}


function encrypt_snull() {
    let inf = 'copyright.txt'
    let outf = 'encrypted_snull.enc'
    cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( algorithm, key, iv )
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( outf )

    let readStream = fs.createReadStream( inf )
    readStream.on( 'data', ( chunk ) => {
        writeStream.write( cipher.update( chunk ) )
    } ).on( 'end', () => {
        writeStream.write( cipher.final() )
        writeStream.end()
    } )
}

function decrypt_snull() {
    let inf = 'encrypted_snull.enc'
    let outf = 'decrypted_snull.txt'
    decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv( algorithm, key, iv )
    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( outf )

    readStream = fs.createReadStream( inf )
    readStream.on( 'data', ( chunk ) => {
        writeStream.write( decipher.update( chunk ) )
    } ).on( 'end', () => {
        writeStream.write( decipher.final() )
        writeStream.end()
    } )
}

function encrypt_shex() {
    let inf = 'copyright.txt'
    let outf = 'encrypted_shex.enc'
    cipher = crypto.createCipheriv( algorithm, key, iv )
    let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( outf )

    let readStream = fs.createReadStream( inf )
    readStream.on( 'data', ( chunk ) => {
        writeStream.write( cipher.update( chunk, 'utf8', 'hex' ) )
    } ).on( 'end', () => {
        writeStream.write( cipher.final( 'hex' ) )
        writeStream.end()
    } )
}

function decrypt_shex() {
    let inf = 'encrypted_shex.enc'
    let outf = 'decrypted_shex.txt'
    decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv( algorithm, key, iv )
    writeStream = fs.createWriteStream( outf )

    readStream = fs.createReadStream( inf )
    readStream.on( 'data', ( chunk ) => {
        writeStream.write( decipher.update( chunk, 'hex', 'utf8' ) )
    } ).on( 'end', () => {
        writeStream.write( decipher.final( 'utf8' ) )
        writeStream.end()
    } )
}


/// work
// encrypt_pnull()
// decrypt_pnull()

/// fail
// encrypt_phex()
// decrypt_phex()

/// work
// encrypt_snull()
// decrypt_snull()

/// fail
// encrypt_shex()
// decrypt_shex()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on the decrypt side. `encrypted_phex.enc` has a base64-encoded string (because "base64" instead of "hex" is used in your example). However, `decipher.setEncoding('base64')` specifies the `decipher` transform stream to receive unencoded buffers and output base64-encoded strings. To make it work, we need to decode the base64 encoding first before deciphering, and we don't need to encode the output with base64 again.

Here is a naive implementation of base64 decoding before deciphering. It might not be efficient for large data because it buffers all the chunks and decode at once. The `decode()` function could be replaced with more efficient implementation<sup>[1]</sup>, but this should work at least (assuming that you call `decrypt_phex()` after `encrypt_phex()` finishes writing the file).

```
function decode(encoding) {
  const chunks = [];
  return new stream.Transform({
    transform(chunk, _encoding, callback) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
      callback();
    },
    flush(callback) {
      const str = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();
      const decoded = Buffer.from(str, encoding);
      callback(null, decoded);
    }
  });
}

function decrypt_phex() {
  let inf = "encrypted_phex.enc";
  let outf = "decrypted_phex.txt";
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);

  inp_enc = fs.createReadStream(inf);
  let decrypted = fs.createWriteStream(outf);
  inp_enc
    .pipe(decode("base64"))
    .pipe(decipher)
    .pipe(decrypted);
}
```

**EDIT**

The `.on("data").on("end")` version has a similar problem in encoding. [The `encoding` parameters (utf8, hex, base64, etc.)](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) are valid only for strings. We don't need them when receiving or outputting `Buffer`s.

[The documentation of `Cipher`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_update_data_inputencoding_outputencoding) says:

> Updates the cipher with data. If the inputEncoding argument is given, the data argument is a string using the specified encoding. If the inputEncoding argument is not given, data must be a Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. If data is a Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView, then inputEncoding is ignored.

And, to make Node.js components understand the "hex" encoding, we need to convert `Buffer`s into strings. Here is an example using the `decode()` function from above.

```
function encrypt_shex() {
  let inf = "copyright.txt";
  let outf = "encrypted_shex.enc";
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outf);

  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(inf);
  readStream
    .on("data", chunk => {
      // The second argument is not necessary because `chunk` is a Buffer.
      writeStream.write(cipher.update(chunk, null, "hex"));
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      writeStream.write(cipher.final("hex"));
      writeStream.end();
    });
}

function decrypt_shex() {
  let inf = "encrypted_shex.enc";
  let outf = "decrypted_shex.txt";
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outf);

  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(inf);
  readStream
    // Decode hex string into a Buffer
    .pipe(decode("hex"))
    .on("data", chunk => {
      writeStream.write(decipher.update(chunk));
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      writeStream.write(decipher.final());
      writeStream.end();
    });
}
```

We could think about decoding the hex string in the `data` handler like the following. However, this approach has a problem because the hex encoding represents one byte with two characters (two bytes). Although it works as long as `chunk` has even number of bytes, when the `chunk` below has an odd number of bytes, `decipher` can't understand it and throws an error `TypeError: Bad input string`.

```
function decrypt_shex() {
  let inf = "encrypted_shex.enc";
  let outf = "decrypted_shex.txt";
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv);
  let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(outf);

  let readStream = fs.createReadStream(inf);
  readStream
    .on("data", chunk => {
      // `chunk` is a Buffer, so convert it into a string before giving it as a hex string to `decipher`.
      writeStream.write(decipher.update(chunk.toString("ascii"), "hex"));
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      writeStream.write(decipher.final());
      writeStream.end();
    });
}
```

<sup>[1]</sup> Streaming implementations should be more efficient for large data. For example: [b64](https://github.com/hapijs/b64). I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. It works. However, why the update() final() version, function decrypt_shex() and encrypt_shex() not work. I THINK I did everything in a proper way.

Comment: I updated my answer covering the `.on("data").on("end")` version.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. However I can't 'tick' your answer twice.

Comment: Haha, no problem :)